# How to target a child element that has class in its parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to target a parent element within its child element. If that child element has a particular class named `caption1`, the image will float left, if `caption2`, the image will float right. I debugged the code in the browser and noticed it skipped over, which means to me that the condition was false, how do I make the required condition statement `if($('#opt-pos-img-responsive > div').hasClass('.caption2'))` true depending on the class name to decide whether to float left or right?

I recreated a [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/prcckg8w/) of the problem I am having. Code is also below.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="opt-pos-img-responsive" href="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive">
        <!--<div class="caption1"> 
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <h3></h3>
        </div>-->
        <div class="caption2"> 
<!--
<h2>Lorem Ipsum <br/><span>dolor<br/> sit amet</span> elit</h2>
<h3></h3>
<button class="btn">Learn More</button>
-->
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</h2>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> sed diam</h3>
            <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
        </div>
</a>
```

**JS:**

```
// remove certain classes and styles for devices less than 991px
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#opt-pos-img-responsive > div').css('border','1px dotted blue');
        if($('#opt-pos-img-responsive > div').hasClass('.caption2')) // check whether it has the class and change img position
        {
            $('img-responsive').css('float','right !important');
        }
        else if($('#opt-pos-img-responsive > div').hasClass('.caption1'))
        {
            $('img-responsive').css('float','left !important');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: change `hasClass('.caption2')` to `hasClass('caption2')` without the period.

Comment: `$('img-responsive')` you didnt use the correct selector, img-responsive is a class which needs to have a `.` in front if it: `$('.img-responsive')`

Comment: Have you considered using pure CSS for this? I think everything can be achieved inside a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) like `@media (max-width: 990px) {}`. This would also apply if the browser is resized, compared to the current jQuery solution does not responsively change the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when the caption has class "caption1" the img should float left. If the caption has class "caption2" the image should float right.

To do this you can check the image's siblings and their classes.

```
$("img").each(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings().hasClass("caption1")) {
      $(this).css("float", "left");
    } else if ($(this).siblings().hasClass("caption2")) {
      $(this).css("float", "right");
    }
  });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prcckg8w/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
(function(){
if(
$("#opt-pos-img-responsive").find("div").hasClass("caption1")){
    $(".img-responsive").css({"float":"left"})
}
else{
    $(".img-responsive").css({"float":"right"})
}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand exactly what you want to achieve, but if you want to target the parent element of an element with a given class, you can do something like this:

```
$('.caption-one').each(function(){
  var $el = $(this.parentElement);
  $el.css('float', 'left');
});
$('.caption-two').each(function(){
  var $el = $(this.parentElement);
  $el.css('float', 'right');
});
```

This will float the parent of caption one to the left and caption two to the right.

Comment: In jQuery it's called `.each()` instead of `.forEach()`, and you don't need it anyway. Just do `$(".caption-one").parent().css("float", "left")`

Comment: Yeah, that also works if the only thing you want is to access that specific attribute. I imagined they would want more juggling with the parent though.